# UIWebView and touch event

Tags: swift, ios5, uiwebview, touch-event

I want use a custom touch event in a view. There is a web view which is the subview of this view.
I override touchBegan and other functions but it does not run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to call a function while tapping a view you can use UITapGestureRecognizer

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: "handleSingleTap:")
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}

func handleSingleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //Do something here with the gesture
}
```

For Swift 3:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(handleSingleTap))
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}

@objc func handleSingleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //Do something here with the gesture
}
```

Comment: I have known that. I mean there is another webview in this and cover it. The view cannot receive the event or gesture.@mrBallista

Comment: have you tried to disable webview interection 
webView.userInteractionEnabled = false

Comment: but I can not operate the webview. I want to using both of the.

Comment: ok , maybe we need to see some code to look what you actually want to do

Comment: I have done with it. The gesture can be used. Sorry.