# is WKCompositingView blocking touches?

Tags: swift, wkwebview, uitapgesturerecognizer, uitouch

I have a WKWebView that I would like to handle touches but I just can't find the right method.

webView is created programmatically in viewDidLoad, and loads fine.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let site = "http://google.com"
    let url = URL(string: site)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.uiDelegate = self // is this necessary for UITouch recognition?
    webView.load(request)
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
}
```

I've tried adding UITapGestureRecognizer in viewDidLoad... (per [UIWebView and touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448044/uiwebview-and-touch-event))

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    //...
    let taprecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapLocation))
    taprecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    taprecognizer.delegate = self
    webView.addGestureRecognizer(taprecognizer)
}

func tapLocation(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    print("tapped")
    return true
}
```

I've also tried getting touch from...

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("tapped")
}
```

My Debug View Hierarchy shows a bunch of WKCompositingViews which makes me think that these are using the touches before they can arrive to WKWebView or View.
[image]

I've added UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to class...but it just won't go through.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: You mean you want to  handle touch in `WKWebView` or you want to handle links in WebView?

Comment: @Superman I was trying to handle touches occurring within the bounds of `WKWebview`. I believe I was doing so in order to use links, but I learned to use `evaluateJavaScript` instead so I still have found a solution to this issue.

Comment: How did you solve this with evaluateJavaScript?

Comment: @RobertVeringa i solved my goal. not this issue.

Comment: hi @Chameleon can i get the avplayer from debugging webview? see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview/55443242?noredirect=1#comment97612916_55443242

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample working code in which i added WKWebView into main view and i am able to detect WKWebView touch event using **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate**

**Swift4**

```
    //
    //  WebViewVC.swift
    //
    //  Created by Test user on 01/02/18.
    //  Copyright © 2018 Test user. All rights reserved.
    //

    import UIKit
    import WebKit

    class WebViewVC: UIViewController,WKUIDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

        var webView : WKWebView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let site = "http://google.com"
            let url = URL(string: site)
            let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
            webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
            webView.uiDelegate = self // is this necessary for UITouch recognition?
            webView.load(request)
            self.view.addSubview(webView)

            let taprecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapLocation))
            taprecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            taprecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
            taprecognizer.delegate = self
            webView.addGestureRecognizer(taprecognizer)
        }

        @objc func tapLocation(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            print("tapped")
            return true
        }

        func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            print("Tap event will detect here.")
            return true
        }

    }
```